# How can I use flex on windows?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to compile a project on windows and it uses flex/bison.

Compiling the flex and bison files went fine after I installed MinGW, but when I get to the final step of the build of:

```
g++ -o hexciting CommandParser.tab.o CommandParser.yy.o Command.o -lfl
```

It says the library can't be found.

After some time on google, I tried changing the flag to -llibfl.a, but this library was also unable to be found.

How can I either get a copy of this library or build one myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm ?

Comment: Turns out the flex I was using wasn't from mingw, but from my AVR toolchain. *doh*

Answer (score 2):

I use flex via cygwin, and then compile in Visual Studio, to avoid having to link the library "l", you just need to define

```
int yywrap()
```

This function is called when the current file is finished, if yywrap return 0 a new file has been loaded, 1 when no more files exist.

For another one of your questions I hard code yywrap to return 1, as it is taking input from standard-in verse files.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Win flex-bison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/). It is very easy to use in Visual Studio.